# Django admin panel css not working as expected in digital ocean server

Tags: python, css, django, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy Django project in digital ocean. My site’s CSS is working perfectly but my admin panel CSS is not working good. The dashboard of the database window overrides my entry page always.

Before few days it seems to be working good but now the CSS makes the whole page messy.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Do you change styling in your admin panel?

Comment: no i dind't change anything but i found something wired when i changed the port number the css works correctly

Comment: no i dind't change anything but i found something weird when i changed the port number the css works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are github to get to your on production server please delete your delete your static root directory on production and generate that by the following command
"python manage.py collectstatic"
i my case

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assests')
```

"assests" is my static root folder, i deleted that entire folder after cloning my repo to the production server and afterwards i generated assessts folder by the command
"python manage.py collectstatic"